# Can’t add comment value to camVariable

Tags: javascript, angular, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to add my selectedDocuments object ‘comment’ item with it’s value (so that i want to show this input in a form where this selectedDocuments object values are rendered and after submmiting this input i want it to be added to selectedDocuments object ) i have tried several varaints here is my code:

```
var variableManager = camForm.variableManager;
$scope.refusalComment=null;

camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
    // tell the form SDK to fetch the variable named 'document'
    variableManager.fetchVariable('selectedDocuments');
});

camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
   // work with the variable (bind it to the current AngularJS $scope)
   $scope.refusalComment = variableManager.variable('refusalComment').value;

   console.log( $scope.refusalComment+"=========refusalComment==========");

   $scope.selectedDocuments =ConvertToJsonArray(variableManager.variable('selectedDocuments').value);    
});

function ConvertToJsonArray(arr){
    //I  have  replaced FinalResult with data
    var  jsonArray=[];
    var json=$scope.json={};
    var json1=$scope.json1={};
    var json2=$scope.json2={};
    json=JSON.parse(arr);
    json1=json.FinalResult;
    json2=JSON.parse(json1);

    //console.log(json1);
    return json2;
}

function EnrichValue(data,comment){
    var json=$scope.json={};
    var json1=$scope.json1={};
    json=JSON.parse(data);
    json1=json.FinalResult;
    json1=JSON.parse(json1);

    for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(json1).length;i++){
       json1[i].comment=comment;
    }

    console.log(json1);
    return json1;
}
```

and  here  is  my   html code:

```
<div class="control-group"  >
            <label for="id" class="control-label">code</label>
             <div class="controls">
              <input id="id" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.id"  required  readonly/>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="control-group" >
            <label for="cardNumber" class="control-label">number </label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input id="cardNumber" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.cardNumber" required />
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="control-group"  >
            <label for="organizationNameGE" class="control-label" >name</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input id="organizationNameGE" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.organizationNameGE"  required />
            </div>
          </div>
              <div class="control-group"  >
            <label for="organizationNameEN" class="control-label">write  comment </label>
           <div class="controls">
              <input id="comment" class="form-control" type="text" cam-variable-name="comment" cam-variable-type="String" value="write  comment" />
            </div>
          </div>  

          </div>   

                <div class="container">
                <div class="control-group" >
                <label for="approved" class="control-label">approve</label>  
                <input type="checkbox" id="approved"
               class="form-control" 
               cam-variable-name="approved"
               cam-variable-type="Boolean"/> 
               </div>  
                </div>  

        </form>
```

when i run this code i always got this error cann’t get value of undefined ( i mean comment)
what should i cjange to make this code work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't see any point in your code where you instantiate the variable comment. I'd suggest to add:

```
var comment = '';
```

to your JS code.